# Is it a good idea to make table view in container view in table view cell?

Tags: ios, tableview

I have to implement view like this in the picture:

[image]

That view should have `cells` which contains expandable content views (number of that views is unknown in advance). When some view hasn't got any content, they shouldn't be expandable.

I don't have much experience but I have some idea but I don't know if it's a good solution:
I want to make `table view` which prototype cell have container view which refers to another table view.

Do I go in this direction?
Or, is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you should use section propery

Comment: having click on section ,add number of rows in section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return noOfSection;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 0) {

            return noOfRows1;            
    }
    else if(section == 1)
     {
        return noOfRows2;
    }

   else if(section == 2)
    {
     return noOfRows3;    
    }
   else
    {
    return 0;

    }
```

> noOfSection = how many you want take section
>   noOfRows1,noOfRows2 and noOfRows3 are numberOfRowsInSection

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it as UITableViewCell's cannot contain Container views. Following exception will be thrown at run time:

> Illegal Configuration: Container Views cannot be placed in elements
>   that are repeated at runtime.

Putting container views in table view cells is way too heavy. Table view cells should be lightweight so the user can scroll through them quickly. It's not necessary to put the entire view controller in each cell. The cell should just represent some of the data for that row.

And I forgot to answer your question in the title:

> It is a bad practice to use container views inside UITableViewCells. It will immensely impact performance and memory of the application.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks!